# Sort a list in ascending order by date from sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sorting, android-cursor

I am having a code for retrieving data like this. I wanted to get records with the dates in the ascending order.I tried using "KEY_DATE_TIME ASC" . but it didnt work.

```
public Cursor fetchAllReminders() {

return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
        KEY_BODY, KEY_PHONE,KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype of the key_date_time column?

Comment: it is string. so can it be sorted just as sorting other strings

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming that KEY_DATE_TIME is a String constant holding the name of the db field, the following should work:

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
        KEY_BODY, KEY_PHONE,KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, null, null, null, KEY_DATE_TIME + " ASC");
```

Comment: @SBerg413 i am trying to sort based on the date time but it is not working, date is being stored as: `2015-09-18T14:15:20.047+05:00`.

Comment: ASC is default in SQL. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp.