# how to sort date which stored in database with string

Tags: android, sorting, android-sqlite, android-date, android-query

I am trying to sort

> SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY DATE(date)     // `date` is stored with string

Here is the LogCat

```
11-22 12:50:50.906: I/DB(31388): get :17 Nov 2013 09:36:01
11-22 12:50:50.906: I/DB(31388): get :13 Nov 2013 07:41:29
11-22 12:50:50.907: I/DB(31388): get :12 Nov 2013 11:09:46
11-22 12:50:50.907: I/DB(31388): get :08 Nov 2013 09:13:26
11-22 12:50:50.908: I/DB(31388): get :02 Nov 2013 08:54:26
11-22 12:50:50.908: I/DB(31388): get :27 Oct 2013 08:02:09
11-22 12:50:50.908: I/DB(31388): get :26 Oct 2013 07:42:18
11-22 12:50:50.908: I/DB(31388): get :21 Oct 2013 06:45:18
11-22 12:50:50.909: I/DB(31388): get :19 Oct 2013 07:38:43
11-22 12:50:50.909: I/DB(31388): get :16 Oct 2013 03:12:16
```

**UPDATE from HERE============>>>**

This is not return `long` value. It is always `return 0`.

```
    try {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateTime);
        long milliseconds = date.getTime();
        return milliseconds;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("DB", "err :" + e);
        return 0;
    }
```

I want to sort with latest date 
can anyone spent some time for me..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should put up date into db in miliseconds (Long value).

Comment: can you please elaborate how to do this.????

Comment: what string date you are getting?

Comment: **Sun, 17 Nov 2013 04:06:01 +0000**

This is the String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert you string date into Long Then Put up it into Database:
if you have Date String something like this 22/11/2013 12:10:00 you can simply convert it with the help of **SimpleDateFormater**

```
   public static long convertStringDateToLong(String dateTime){
        try {
            DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            Date d = f.parse(dateTime);
            long milliseconds = d.getTime();
            return milliseconds;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

SimpleDateFormate Depends on you Date String formate.

Comment: first convert String date to Long & put it into DB.
Now you can use simple query
Select * from table name order by datecolumn name desc Limit maxrows
or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051800/sort-a-list-in-ascending-order-by-date-from-sqlite

Comment: yes in which formate you want to shown convert it back into string

Comment: Please give me acknowledge :P :)

Comment: hello sir please see this question `UPDATE` part its return me always 0.

Answer (score 1):

I did this for this my problem..

thank you everybody...

```
public static String convertLongToStringDate(String dateTime) {
    String dateString=null;
    Long l=Long.parseLong(dateTime);
    try {
        Date date=new Date(l);
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        dateString = sdf.format(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return dateString;
    }
    return dateString;
}
```